# IIS 7 - change the allowDefinition attribute for a config section in machine.config

Tags: windows, iis, appcmd

We have a situation where we need to explicitly limit the `system.web/processModel/maxAppDomains = 1` for one website. The problem is that `system.web/processModel` can only be set at the machine.config level by default:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web">
            <section name="processModel" allowDefinition="MachineOnly" />
        </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
<configuration>
```

I know that `%windir%/system32/inetsvr/appcmd.exe` can be used to update IIS config settings, but I haven't found a way to update the `allowDefinition` attribute of the `processModel` section definition. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks

Comment: just to be clear... you know how to set the process model section for a specific site, but you're trying to find a scripted way to modify allowDefinition="blahblah" so that your per-site settings will work?

Comment: That's exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using WMI provider:

```
' SetAllowDefinition is a static method, you should call it by getting a class object, as in the following example  
Set oAnonAuth = oWebAdmin.Get("AnonymousAuthenticationSection")
oAnonAuth.SetAllowDefinition "MachineOnly"
```

based on my understanding, i think you are intersted in setting AllowDefinition to [AppHostOnly] or [MachineToApplication] values.

ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386461(v=vs.90).aspx

note: Changes to the ProcessModelSection class take effect only when the worker process is restarted, not immediately after the setting is changed.

i used the following code to set maxAppDomain=1 to the current web app "but you can change it for any .config file by providing the path"

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("");
            System.Web.Configuration.ProcessModelSection processModelSection =
                        (ProcessModelSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/processModel");
            processModelSection.MaxAppDomains = 1;
```

hope that's help, yet i had to assume couple of things since the question requirements need further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the machine.config file directly?  Every time I've run into issues with the machine.config file I've just edited the file directly.

Comment: The problem is that we need to do this as part of a deployment, so automating it in some way is our preferred option.